# Issue to open credentials file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am trying to open credentials file with this command.

```
rails credentials:edit
```

It returns :

> No $EDITOR to open file in. Assign one like this:
>
> EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
>
> For editors that fork and exit immediately, it's important to pass a
>   wait flag, otherwise the credentials will be saved immediately with no
>   chance to edit.

So I make this command :

```
EDITOR="subl --w" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

However, terminal responds with "New credentials encrypted and saved" without opening an editor.

Comment: I just answered it [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756479/9823976](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756479/9823976) This may help you.

Answer (score 12):

Are you using the correct alias for `wait`?
In official documentation there is:
`-w or --wait: Wait for the files to be closed before returning`

So it should be:
`EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`.

I've just tested this on ubuntu with vs code, and atom and it worked correctly:
`EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit`.
`EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit`.

Also check if subl is correctly added to system variable path.

Comment: Yes I did it didn't change , i get the same issue

Comment: yes i try it by credentials are not saving

Answer (score 6):

```
EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit
```

example using any environment:

```
EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit --environment=production
```

Answer (score 4):

As a VS Code user, this took me a while to figure out. What was missing to install the `code` command through VS Code's interface.

Crossposting [Bryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961858/vscode-doesnt-wait-on-command-editor-code-wait-bin-rails-credentialsedit) answer here:

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type `shell command` to find the Shell Command: Install `code` command in PATH command.
- Now run `EDITOR="code --w" bin/rails credentials:edit`

There might be a similar missing step for Sublime users.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, I was facing the same problem and found that code command was not installed in VS editor. It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

For all the **Windows 10/11 users**:
setup the editor using the following command:

```
$env:EDITOR="notepad"
```

Now run this command to edit the credentials file:

```
bundle exec rails credentials:edit --environment development
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run `vim` inside of a devcontainer:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim

EDITOR="vim --nofork" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Comment: thank the stars for you.. really happy to have vim editing for this. nofork.. should have known.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As nuaky answered, the following command helps me (assume terminal command line in app folder):

$ EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I spent a good hour trying to get this answer. The following worked for me

MAC - Catalina 10.15.4
Rails Version= 6.0.3.2
Ruby Version= 2.7.0

I run on the terminal

```
EDITOR="subl -w" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

And it allowed me to edit the `credentials.yml.enc` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue fixed by setting my editor to sublime text in the terminal like this:

```
export EDITOR="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -w"
```

Then running `rails credentials:edit`  again

`-w` will make sure that changes are saved when you exit the editor.