# Why I can not use a ready-made credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials

I want to use ready-made credential, that are on my server.

I do `EDITOR="nano --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`

Then I replace the contents of credentials.yml.enc and master.key with the ones inside these files on my server.
But when I try to read credentials I get an error `Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says it all: to use credentials files from your server, you should have same key in `config/master.key` file (or `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable, depending on how you set it)

Comment: I replaced the contents of the created master.key with the contents of master.key from the server.

Comment: @SsPay production key might be in RAILS_MASTER_KEY environment variable or config/credentials/production.key on server and differ from one in master.key there

Answer (score 5):

If you using the credentials and the master key for the first time and haven't used them from anywhere else. I'd propose you to do the following;

1. Delete the `credentials.yml.enc` and the `master.key`
2. Run `EDITOR="nano --wait" rails credentials:edit`. This will create both the credentials and the master key.

This worked for me when I got stuck.