# VSCode doesn't wait on command: EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit

Tags: visual-studio-code

Newly using VS Code (from Atom).

When attempting to edit my credentials file with the following command:

`EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`

The --wait operation does not wait. After a few seconds my terminal responds:

`File encrypted and saved.`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seemed to work for me. Ended up searching for opening Code in terminal. Found this, and this solved my problem.

Launch VS Code.

Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install

'code' command in PATH command.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: This has fixed something that's been annoying me for months. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped