# Git commit in VSCode aborts before closing commit file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

When I try to type `git commit` my terminal opens a file in VSC like I want it to, but will not wait for me to close the file before returning `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

I can confirm that code is accessible to my terminal, git is accessible, and here is my git config:

```
[safe]
    directory = D:/repo
[user omitted for privacy]
[core]
  editor = code --wait
[diff]
  tool = vscode
[difftool "code"]
  cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
  tool = code
[mergetool "vscode"]
  cmd = code --wait $MERGED
```

Here is an additional image showing the behavior:
[image: Behavior]

I've been searching all over the internet for this. The only similar question I've found is

[VSCode doesn't wait on command: EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961858/vscode-doesnt-wait-on-command-editor-code-wait-bin-rails-credentialsedit)

However I have a Windows machine and no such "Shell Command" pops up for me.

It seems as though the --wait flag is not working at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not simply do it inline `git commit -m "FIX: Your awesome brief commit message that is helpful to others"`?

Comment: Does anything from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+code+wait+empty+commit+message help?