# How to open credentials.yml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `credentials.yml` file stores an app's secrets as an encrypted file. How do you open it (to view/edit it)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue to open credentials file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370065/issue-to-open-credentials-file)

Answer (score 3):

To open in vim (e.g. in the terminal):

```
EDITOR=vi bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Or to open in sublime text, something like:

```
EDITOR="Sublime --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```